# Add angular2 into existing nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I was given an existing big ass nodejs app which contains both the UI and the back-end logic. I would like to split them up and am thinking of using AngularJS 2 for the UI part.

I have gone through some of the examples and know my way around Angular. However I do not know how to properly install it on the existing nodejs app - what do I include in the package.json .... what do I do with the systemjs.config.js, tsconfig.js and typing.json ? How to include the "typescript" parsing/compilation ?

Thank you

P.S. the nodejs app is running sailsJS framework.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @tcooc The thing is I already have package.json file ... because of the nodejs - sails app

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to split the app into 2 layers  (assuming this is possible):

1) the REST service layer

2) the Angular2 Front End layer

Node.js (maybe with the help of express) would run the REST service piece.

Angular2 would be the Front End part, calling the REST services offered by the Node server.

In such a scenario you would not have to 'install' Angular2 on Node. You rather would have to prepare a development environment (I suggest to use also Angular2 CLI) for Angular and start the development against the available services. Unfortunately these means that it may be difficult for you to reuse whatever pure FE logic has been developed so far (maybe with the exception of the css part).

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey man. Yeah this is what I have figured as well. My question is more about the exact steps in including the Angular in the node app. What to write in the package.json, how to configure the systemjs ... I was looking at the CLI thing ...

Comment: You do not have to do anything specific in the configuration of Angular. You just need the Http service which is by default already defined when you setup an Angular environment both using Angular-CLI and the angular.io quickstart (if I remember correctly). Node itself does not know that an Angular client app is calling. It could be anyone.